# Not able to create React App project on vs code

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx, react-error-boundary

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

npx clear-npx-cache is not working for me ....plz help

how to solve this error .I have used following step but still not working.
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npm cache clean --force”

npm cache verify

npx create-react-app my-app

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, run these commands in sequence

```
npm init
npm install create-react-app@latest
npx create-react-app myapp
```